# Split sns.barplot by col or row

Tags: python, plot, graph, seaborn

I'd like to split my sns.barplot so that a second row or column can show a second condition. Specifically, I am hoping to use sns.barplot and not catplot of facetgrid so that I can display the heights of my bars, as well as control the tick_params. Does anyone have advice? The below is an example using the `titantic` dataset.

Currently working code *without* split by e.g., sex:

```
url = "https://raw.github.com/mattdelhey/kaggle-titanic/master/Data/train.csv"
titanic = pd.read_csv(url)

g = sns.barplot(data=titanic, 
            x='embarked',
            y='fare', 
            )

plt.ylim(0, 100)

#add height of bars
for p in g.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    g.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2,
            height+20,
            '{:}'.format(height.round(2)),
            ha="center") 

g.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
```

What I would like is something like this, where I can split the graphs into 2 columns by sex:

```
g = sns.barplot(data=titanic, 
            x='embarked',
            y='fare', 
            col='sex',
            )

plt.ylim(0, 100)

#add height of bars
for p in g.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    g.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2,
            height+20,
            '{:}'.format(height.round(2)),
            ha="center") 

g.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
```

Again, while I know that catplot is able to do this, I lose the ability to display the height of the bars. Also `hue` is not quite what I'm looking for, since my actual dataset is more complex than the `titanic` dataset and each condition should be displayed in it's own section. Thank you!

Comment: What about using `hue`? As in `sns.barplot(data=titanic, x='embarked', y='fare', hue='sex')`?

Comment: "Again, while I know that catplot is able to do this, I lose the ability to display the height of the bars." I can't see how this would be.

Comment: Thanks for your note @mwaskom — I receive this error when I attempt to display the height of my bars with catplot: `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'patches'` Perhaps could you offer advice on how to display the bar heights with catplot?

Comment: The `patches` list is a property of an `Axes`. A `FacetGrid` has multiple `Axes` objects. So you just need another layer in your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @mwaskom `sns.catplot` is a `FacetGrid` object with multiple `Axes` that you need to loop through. You can accomplish this with `for ax in g.axes.flat:` and THEN `for p in ax.patches:`. Also, you need to pass `kind='bar' to` catplot`and change`g.text`to`ax.text`:

```
url = "https://raw.github.com/mattdelhey/kaggle-titanic/master/Data/train.csv"
titanic = pd.read_csv(url)
#----------------------------------------
g = sns.catplot(data=titanic, 
            x='embarked',
            y='fare', 
        col='sex', kind='bar')

plt.ylim(0, 100)

# add height of bars
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    for p in ax.patches:
        height = p.get_height()
        ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2,
                height+20,
                '{:}'.format(height.round(2)),
                ha="center") 

    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize=20)
```

[image]